# Skipping confussion about First Qibla of Islam

Tags: quran, reference-request, qiblah, masjid-al-haram

One subject is not clear to me that prophet muhammad (sm) prayed for 16 or 17 months to Al-Aqsa as Qibla but not 13 years. Then at that time what was the muslim's Qibla? we know that Qabah was the first worship house in this earth and first house too. Hazrat Ibrahim (A) and Ismail (A) built Qabah and he is the father of muslims. In my opinion Qabah is the first Qibla but i want to know actual thing. Is any verse in Holy Quran or Hadith that actually makes Al-Aqsa as the first Qibla?

Comment: Nope but there are many verses for the masjid al-Haram as second in surat al-baqara! Read this post https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33603/about-namaz-direction-in-masjide-aqsa for more information. See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27752/interior-of-kaaba/27766#27766

Comment: I don't understand what this sentence is asking "... prophet muhammad (sm) prayed for 16 or 17 months to Al-Aqsa as Qibla but not 13 years. Then at that time what was the muslim's Qibla?"  Where is the 16/17 months vs. 13 years referring to?  At *what* time?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones well the first qiblah in Islam was al-Masjid al-Aqsa in Jerusalem or al-Quds and the prayer has been officially ordered 2 years before hijrah and the qiblah change has taken place in Medina as the narrations show and the second and lasting qiblah is al-Masjid al-Haram I don't know if this clears your confusion...